# widgets not getting displayed in ipywidgets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am a beginner with jupyter notebooks and python. I tried the following (as advised in a youtube video - the sole teacher available for me).

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib nbagg 
x = np.linspace(0,2,1000)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize =(10,4))

amp=widgets.FloatSlider(min=1,max=10,value=1,description='Amp:')
display(amp)
plt.suptitle('sine wave')
fig.show()
```

The display of the plot is happening (of course without any curves - i did not create them), but the widget doesn't get displayed. Any help in this regard is welcome.

[image]

Comment: Check you have followed the install steps at: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html#with-pip There is a second command to run after 'pip install' in notebook.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try Plotly instead of Matplotlib, use the following code instead:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np


# generate x values
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
 
 
def my_sine(x, w, amp, phi):
    """
    Return a sine for x with angular frequeny w and amplitude amp.
    """
    return amp*np.sin(w * (x-phi))
 
 
@widgets.interact(w=(0, 10, 1), amp=(0, 4, .1), phi=(0, 2*np.pi+0.01, 0.01))
def view_image(w = 1.0, amp=1, phi=0):
    
    y = my_sine(x, w, amp, phi)
    
    fig = px.line(x=x, y=y)
    
    #Fix Y-axis range, otherwise the sine will appear to remain fixed, and only Y-axis values will change.
    fig.update_yaxes(range=(-4, 4))
    #Disable autosizing fo Figure canvas. Otherwise, every time a slider is moved, the canvas size will automatically change.
    fig.update_layout(autosize=False)
    
    fig.show()
```

In order to install Plotly and use it in your notebooks, please read [this](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/) guide.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is normal that a sine wave is not displayed in your case: you only create an empty `Figure` and an `Axes` with `plt.subplots`, and you display a slider which is in no way connected to any plotting function!

I suggest the following code to plot a sine wave with different interacting properties:

```py
%matplotlib widget
import ipywidgets as widgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))
ax.set_ylim([-4, 4])
ax.grid(True)
 
# generate x values
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
 
 
def my_sine(x, w, amp, phi):
    """
    Return a sine for x with angular frequeny w and amplitude amp.
    """
    return amp*np.sin(w * (x-phi))
 
 
@widgets.interact(w=(0, 10, 1), amp=(0, 4, .1), phi=(0, 2*np.pi+0.01, 0.01))
def update(w = 1.0, amp=1, phi=0):
    """Remove old lines from plot and plot new one"""
    [l.remove() for l in ax.lines]
    ax.plot(x, my_sine(x, w, amp, phi), color='C0')
```

The magic command `%matplotlib widget` requires you to install `ipympl`: `conda install -c conda-forge ipympl`.

I took this code from a very good [tutorial](https://kapernikov.com/ipywidgets-with-matplotlib/).

This code works only in single Jupyter Notebooks; in order to use it with Jupyter Lab, it is necessary to install an extension: `jupyter labextension install jupyter-matplotlib`.

I too am currently learning how to use Jupyter widgets to create interactive notebooks!

Comment: Thanks Enrico. I tried using the code you have provided... but i am not able to get the widget appear.

Comment: what is single Jupyter Notebooks ? Jupyter Lab ?

Comment: @Murali
I do not know if you are aware, but you can use Jupyter Notebooks from two different interfaces. The older one is `jupyter notebook`, the newer one is `jupyter lab`, and sometimes they work differently, especially with widgets. I suggest you learn Jupyter Lab, since it will become the standard.
If this answer does not work for you, you should probably install some other dependencies. Check [ipyml GitHub page](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl), especially the section "Use in JupyterLab".

Comment: Thanks. I had tried all methods... different tutorials ... resetting kernals etc., I am not able to get the display of the widget at all. This is quite critical for my project.

Comment: How to troubleshoot this ? I see a lot of discussions on this topic but there are no step-by-step diagnosis for this problem. Are there any other module that i can install to get a widget and update my plots as per the choice made in the widgets... i am okay to walk away from ipywidgets.

Comment: @Murali
It is very complex to troubleshoot this kind of issue, since there is not an actual Error, but an unexpected behavior.
I suggest you start from a clean slate: create a brand new conda environment for this project, and install all required modules: matplotlib, jupyter, ipywidgets, ipyml, jupyterlab.
In this environment, also install all required jupyter extensions.
I am quite sure that you have to use ipywidgets, there are no other options. Every tool that displays something interactive on your notebook relies on ipywidgets.

Comment: @Murali
I also posted another answer, based on Plotly instead of Matplotlib. Of course, ipywidgets are still required, but it shouldn't be too hard to install them properly, if you are using Anaconda.

Comment: it is really painful... no error but the objective is not met... i will try creating a new environment altogether...and try my luck.

Comment: @Murali
The best of luck for your project!
If my answers were useful in any way, an upvote would be appreciated!